# Javascript - can I check if a tab opened with javascript is still open ? (without Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, tabs

I would like to know if it would be possible to check the existence of a tab with pure javascript. I know how to do this with a chrome extension but I'm wondering if it's possible with JS.

Creating the tab:

```
window.open("https://www.google.com", 'mytab');
```

Can I check if "mytab" is open ? And if it is open, does it have the focus? Using window.open may be blocked by pop-up blockers and because of this, I don't know if the tab has been opened.

My gut feeling tells me it's not possible with pure JS but I'm not an expert, that's why I'm asking. I have checked this on stackoverflow but I see mainly solution with a browser extension.

If know another work around, I'm also interested.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know of would be to implicitly check via if your page still has visibility / focus so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/16288497) may help you further.